# The spaces $K^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $C^{\mathbb{N}}$, both with the product topology, are homeomorphic to each other.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

can anyone please guide me through b? I am confident in my proof for a, however, I would like some guidance for b. Does b just follow from a? The space we are dealing with is Hausdorff. Thank you!

Let $K=\{0,1,2,3\}$ and let $C=\{0,1\}$. Prove:

$(a)$ For any $n\in \mathbb{N}, K^n$ with the product topology is homeomorphic to $C^{2n}$ with the product topology.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Since the intention is that $K$ and $C$ both have the discrete topology, then the product spaces $K^n$ and $C^{2n}$ are homeomorphic. The sets $K^n$ and $C^{2n}$ have both cardinality $2^{2n}$ and therefore there exists a bijection between them. The product topologies on $K^n$ and $C^{2n}$ are both discrete. More generally, for any finite, discrete topological space $X$ and any integer $k\ge 1$, the product topology on $X^k$ is discrete. Any bijection between discrete topological spaces is homeomorphic.

$(b)$ The spaces $K^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $C^{\mathbb{N}}$, both with the product topology, are homeomorphic to each other.

Comment: You question does not make any sense if you you do not tell us which topologies are used on $K$ and $C$. In your "proof" you indicate that $K$ has the indiscrete topology and $C$ has the discrete topology. If that is assumed, (a) is certainly not true.

Comment: @PaulFrost we are dealing with $T_2$

Comment: The topology $\{\emptyset,K\}$ is not Hausdorff if $K$ has more than one element, and in fact your $K$ has four elements. What is $\{1,2\}$ doing in your purported topology on $C=\{0,1\}$?

Comment: @rudinsimons12 Okay, then you should omit the first sentence of your proof. This prevents misunderstanding.

Comment: @PaulFrost ok, but I thought $T_2$ indicates Hausdorff? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @rudinsimons12 You are right. But reading the first sentence of your proof produces doubts what you really mean. That is why I recommended to omit it.

Comment: @PaulFrost I see, okay I will omit it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the first, the finite spaces are Hausdorff and thus must be discrete. The finite products are also discrete and have the same size, and so are homeomorphic. Done.

That the countable powers of finite discrete spaces are homeomorphic is a consequence of Brouwer’s theorem that all countable metrisable zero-dimensional spaces without isolated points are homeomorphic.  But there is an easier argument in this case because you can write the power of $C$ as the power of $K$ using an odd/even partition of $\mathbb{N}$. Just group by 2, and use only that $C \times C \simeq K$.

Comment: Thank you Henno!